# How Can I Add APIs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I Want to add Facebook, googlemap ang twitter APIs to my application.. as i want to call them on button click so that i can share something on respective sites.

please tell me how can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twitter](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/), [Facebook](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app), [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html).

Answer (score 0):

Something worth looking at might be [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/).
This adds easy support for importing those APIs!